# using appcmd to set physical path of an IIS10 website

Tags: iis, iis-10

How can I use appcmd in IIS10 to set the physical path of a website?

Something like...

```
appcmd set site summit /[path='/'].path:c:\newpath
```

This is the setting I am trying to change...

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/application/virtualdirectory#appcmdexe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the site physical path using below command:

```
appcmd set site /site.name:"site name" /application[path='/'].virtualDirectory[path='/'].physicalPath:"D:\newpath"
```

[image]

Do not forget to run the command prompt as administrator.